# JS files not being loaded in Nuxt project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working with a bootstrap template and am trying to implement it into a Nuxt project. I believe I have loaded all the necessary files except for the scripts.

I am importing my scripts into `nuxt.config.js`. I have tried doing this a couple different ways:

1.) I have tried including the local src paths like this:

```
script: [
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/popper.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/parallax.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.appear.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/revolution-addons/before-after-affect/revolution.addon.beforeafter.min.js'}
  ],
```

2.) And as static files:

```
script: [
    { src: '/js/jquery.js' },
    { src: '/js/popper.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/bootstrap.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/parallax.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/jquery.appear.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/revolution-addons/before-after-affect/revolution.addon.beforeafter.min.js'}
  ],
```

My entire `nuxt.config.js` file looks like this:

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/style.css',
    '~/assets/css/animate.css',
    '~/assets/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css',
    '~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    '~/assets/css/cubeportfolio.min.css',
    // '~/assets/css/fontawesome-all.min'
    '~/assets/css/green.css',
    '~/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css',
    '~/assets/css/layer.css',
    '~/assets/css/morphext.css',
    '~/assets/css/navigation.css',
    '~/assets/css/settings.css',
    '~/assets/css/swiper.min.css',
    '~/assets/css/themify-icons.css',
    '~/assets/css/yellow.css',
    '~/assets/css/revolution-addons/before-after-affect/revolution.addon.beforeafter.css',
    '~/assets/css/revolution-addons/particles-effect/revolution.addon.particles.css'
  ],
  script: [
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/popper.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/parallax.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.appear.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/revolution-addons/before-after-affect/revolution.addon.beforeafter.min.js'}
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

When inspecting the page, I am not seeing any of the script files listed which is what seems to be preventing the rest of this bootstrap theme from loading properly.

It should look like this:
http://www.themesindustry.com/html/treely/index.html

My entire repo can be found here:
https://github.com/SIeep/brandon-evans-portfolio

Would really appreciate any sort of guidance or help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `scripts` array should be inside `head` object like so:

```js
export default {
  ...
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  script: [
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/popper.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/parallax.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.appear.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js' },
    { src: '~assets/js/revolution-addons/before-after-affect/revolution.addon.beforeafter.min.js'}
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sweet! I think this worked! That makes perfect sense too. I do now see them in the inspector and I see some changes, so I believe this worked.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `import` statement and webpack instead of importing all this js files. This isn't good practice.

Also, I'm not sure property `script` exist for nuxt. However, if you really want to do that, you can import your file in your `head` content, like this example:

```js
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css' }
    ],
    script: [
      { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'}
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Where would I use the ```import``` statement at? I'm new to Nuxt and thought they should all be loaded in the nuxt.config.js. I also missed that I didn't put the script array in the ```head```. This seemed to fix the issue so thank you!